# Whole page reloading after changing one state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I'm currently building a page with a ton of Charts, and I'm using a Material UI menu to kinda switch around graphs.
When I click on a new MenuItem it changes my part state and displays a new array of components.
My main problem right now is that whenever I click on the button, all the charts do a quick load, but with this amount of charts this is a problem.
I've tried debugging it, but to be honest I couldn't find a problem, all my states are set when they need to be set, and useEffects are running just once on the beginning, so no extra loads. 
This is what it looks like:
[image: charts load]
And this would be the code that I'm currently rendering. If you need any further info from my code just let me know and if you can provide any advice for the improvement of my code I would be glad, thanks.

```
    <>
      <div className={classes.actionBar}>
        <SelectEstimatedMonthForm />
      </div>
      <div>
        <Card>
          <div>
            <h1>Gráficos de DRE</h1>
            <Button
              aria-controls="simple-menu"
              aria-haspopup="true"
              onClick={handleClick}
            >
              Open Menu
            </Button>
            <Menu
              id="simple-menu"
              anchorEl={anchorEl}
              keepMounted
              open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
              onClose={handleClose}
            >
              <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Todos Gráficos</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>
                Gráficos DRE Orçamento Evolução
              </MenuItem>
              <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>
                Gráficos de Evolução Parte 2
              </MenuItem>
              <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>
                Gráficos de Representatividade
              </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
          </div>
          <div>
            {chartDataPart?.part1 && part === 1 && values && (
              <div>
                {chartDataPart?.part1?.map((data) => {
                  if (data?.type === "bar") {
                    return (
                      <div>
                        {data?.labels && (
                          <ChartBar
                            data={data}
                            text={data?.text}
                            noLabel={data?.noLabel}
                            stacked={data?.stacked}
                            newPlugin={data?.customPlugin}
                          />
                        )}
                      </div>
                    );
                  } else if (data?.type === "pie") {
                    return (
                      <div>
                        {data?.labels && (
                          <ChartPie text={data?.text} data={data} />
                        )}
                      </div>
                    );
                  } else if (data?.type === "doughnut") {
                    return (
                      <div>
                        {data?.labels && (
                          <ChartDoughnut text={data?.text} data={data} />
                        )}
                      </div>
                    );
                  } else {
                    return (
                      <div>
                        <h1>{data?.text} esta sem type</h1>
                      </div>
                    );
                  }
                })}
              </div>
            )}
            {chartDataPart?.part2 && part === 2 && values && (
              <div>
                {chartDataPart?.part2?.map((data) => {
                  if (data?.type === "bar") {
                    return (
                      <div>
                        {data?.labels && (
                          <ChartBar
                            data={data}
                            text={data?.text}
                            noLabel={data?.noLabel}
                            stacked={data?.stacked}
                            newPlugin={data?.customPlugin}
                          />
                        )}
                      </div>
                    );
                  } else if (data?.type === "pie") {
                    return (
                      <div>
                        {data?.labels && (
                          <ChartPie text={data?.text} data={data} />
                        )}
                      </div>
                    );
                  } else if (data?.type === "doughnut") {
                    return (
                      <div>
                        {data?.labels && (
                          <ChartDoughnut text={data?.text} data={data} />
                        )}
                      </div>
                    );
                  } else {
                    return (
                      <div>
                        <h1>{data?.text} esta sem type</h1>
                      </div>
                    );
                  }
                })}
              </div>
            )}
            {chartDataPart?.part3 && part === 3 && values && (
              <div>
                {chartDataPart?.part3?.map((data) => {
                  if (data?.type === "bar") {
                    return (
                      <div>
                        {data?.labels && (
                          <ChartBar
                            data={data}
                            text={data?.text}
                            noLabel={data?.noLabel}
                            stacked={data?.stacked}
                            newPlugin={data?.customPlugin}
                          />
                        )}
                      </div>
                    );
                  } else if (data?.type === "pie") {
                    return (
                      <div>
                        {data?.labels && (
                          <ChartPie text={data?.text} data={data} />
                        )}
                      </div>
                    );
                  } else if (data?.type === "doughnut") {
                    return (
                      <div>
                        {data?.labels && (
                          <ChartDoughnut text={data?.text} data={data} />
                        )}
                      </div>
                    );
                  } else {
                    return (
                      <div>
                        <h1>{data?.text} esta sem type</h1>
                      </div>
                    );
                  }
                })}
              </div>
            )}
            {chartData && part === 0 && values && (
              <div>
                {chartData?.map((data) => {
                  if (data?.type === "bar") {
                    return (
                      <div>
                        {data?.labels && (
                          <ChartBar
                            data={data}
                            text={data?.text}
                            noLabel={data?.noLabel}
                            stacked={data?.stacked}
                            newPlugin={data?.customPlugin}
                          />
                        )}
                      </div>
                    );
                  } else if (data?.type === "pie") {
                    return (
                      <div>
                        {data?.labels && (
                          <ChartPie text={data?.text} data={data} />
                        )}
                      </div>
                    );
                  } else if (data?.type === "doughnut") {
                    return (
                      <div>
                        {data?.labels && (
                          <ChartDoughnut text={data?.text} data={data} />
                        )}
                      </div>
                    );
                  } else {
                    return (
                      <div>
                        <h1>{data?.text} esta sem type</h1>
                      </div>
                    );
                  }
                })}
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        </Card>
     </div>
    </>
```

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchDreData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await http.get(
          `call1`
        );
        const data = await res.data;
        const final = data.data;
        // console.log(final);
        setEstimatedMonths(final);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log("error", e);
      }
    };
    const fetchProductsData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await http.get(
          `call2`
        );
        const data = await res.data;
        const final = data.data;
        // console.log(res);
        setEstimatedProducts(final);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log("error", e);
      }
    };
    fetchDreData();
    fetchProductsData();
    // console.log("useffect1");
  }, [estimatedMonthContext.monthId]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (estimatedProducts && estimatedMonths) {
      // console.log("useffect2");
      flatData();
    }
    // productsFlatData();
  }, [estimatedProducts, estimatedMonths]);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    // if (values) {
    chart();
    // console.log("useffect3");
    // }
  }, [values]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something on your page is causing the page to rerender again after load, which would be either a state change or most likely the useEffect.

If you are using useEffect make sure you're doing it correctly by 1. not updating state inside it or 2. returning '[]'.

```
useEffect(() => {

}, []) // this part here
```

Along with that you're fetching data from multiple endpoints and each time updating the state every time the data returns, which will cause the page to rerender multiple times.  Instead you should move each component to their own respective individual components and fetch their own data individually so they don't affect each other and update the whole page.

Comment: I added the useEffect part, but my problem basically is, whenever a state that controls my menu changes the whole chart stuff reloads, but there's nothing related between them.

Comment: Ohhhh I see.  In that case you should move the graphs to individual react components.  In this case all of them are managed by a single state, but if you separate them into multiple components then each will manage their own state.  On top of that you can also then apply more logic in your parent component on how its children should render.  It will also just be better code so everything isn't in one huge file.

Comment: Got it, the problem is that I need to render the stuff on my code conditionaly when someone chooses something on my menu, and moving my menu to a individual component make it impossible to change states to it's parent

Comment: If you see on my earlier code there's some stuff that is rendering after `chartDataPart` and `part` are set, but the part is set when my `MenuItem` is selected, so I would need for this to be in the same component, any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: See updated answer.  Also you can still update stuff from the parent if you pass down a callback to the child, you can pass whatever props that child needs in order to update the parent menu.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh, that actually changes everything, I did not knew that I could pass callbacks functions as props, I'm going to refactor and try it again. Thanks!

Comment: And about the useEffects, i'm indeed going to change that, I will place a Promise.all instead of multiple calls and change the useEffect to one big setState with a few function parameters

Comment: No need to use a promise.all, each should load their own data, you don't only want to update the page when everything is done, you can show each graph the moment it's done loading, but do it in each of their own respective components so they only update themselves.  Then it will look like all the graphs are popping up one by one as they finish loading.